# What's a possible translation for something being "fucked up"?

Tags: coloquialismos, insultos

> “That you guys even think it’s negotiable is pretty fucked up,”

The translation concensus seems to be

> “Que ustedes incluso piensen que es negociable está bastante jodido”,

But it just doesn't have nearly the same impact as the original. All the ways to rephrase the sentence I came up with attack the person more than the idea they're debating.

Comment: You could use "me jode" but doesn't quite have the same ring.  *flipar* probably works better, ¿Piensen que es negociable? Flipo.  Or *que lo piensen que es negociable me flipa*, but that probably works mostly for Spain.  Let us know which country you'd like an answer from so we can better respond

Comment: Francamente, la sugerencia que (cierta cosa) sea negociable me/nos ofende / es increíble.  (Y luego una pausa da más efecto.)

Answer (score 1):

> #### [retorcido, da](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WIFp9kE)
>
> ```
> Del part. de retorcer.
> ```
>
> 1. `adj.` Dicho de una persona: De intención sinuosa.